# I want to update the key value pair of gui.properties file dynamically

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am working with selenium automation. I am in need of updating GUI.properties key-value pair at the run-time. I tried the below codes, but not reflecting changes.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
    try {       
        p.load(PropertyMap.class.getResourceAsStream("/gui.properties"));
        p.setProperty(key, value);
        return p;   

        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In the calling method, I am calling like this

```
PropertyMap.setProperties("SoftwareLifecycleStage.Selectors", "Concept");

clickOnFieldIfValueIsNotNull(getSelectorsXPath(properties.getProperty("Myssi.SoftwareLifecycleStage.Selectors")), "LifecycleStageSelectors");
```

the above method `clickonfieldifvalueisnotnull` is a generic method which just clicks on the given element by `xpath` and `getSelectorsXPath` is just give the `xpath` of that element.

I tried with the following code also...

```
Properties p = new Properties();
   try {
        PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("src/test/resources/gui.properties");          
        config.setProperty(key, value);         
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Please help me in this?

Update:-

Adding

> Config.save(); 
>   is worked for me... But the problem I am facing is After saving the file, I have given Thread.sleep(2000); to just reflect the changes, But it is not picking up the changed values for the next lines. I tried removing thread.sleep, but the same repeating.... After the execution of test, I have checked the gui.properties, the corresponding values have changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to call config.save(); method at end?

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try {
    PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("src/test/resources/gui.properties");          
    config.setProperty(key, value);  
    // call save?
    config.save();
} catch (ConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It is not working, I went to debugging mode and saw it. But, I don't know why it is not working. help me...

Comment: One update is that the value corresponding to that key is changed in gui.properites, so I am going wrong in the next statements I think...

Comment: So what is not working now? The original problem you posted is solved as one property is updated & not sure what is not working now? Ideally you should accept response and then add further question so people are encouraged to help.

Comment: But the problem I am facing is After saving the file, I have given Thread.sleep(2000); to just reflect the changes, But it is not picking up the changed values for the next lines. I tried removing thread.sleep, but the same repeating.... After the execution of test, I have checked the gui.properties, the corresponding values have changed...